# Stop caching in Firefox

Tags: java, jsp, caching, meta-tags

I am using following code.

```
<%
response.addHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
response.addHeader("Pragma","no-cache,no-store,private,must-revalidate,max-stale=0,post-check=0,pre-check=0 "); 
response.addDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
%>
```

It works perfectly in IE, but the page is still cached in Firefox. I want to stop caching in Firefox as well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're confusing `Cache-Control` and `Pragma` headers. Swap them. Firefox namely also requires `no-store` and `must-revalidate` along the `no-cache`.

```
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,private,must-revalidate,max-stale=0,post-check=0,pre-check=0"); 
response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
response.addDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
```

Even more, only the `no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate` has been enough for `Cache-Control` to get it to work across browsers.

#### See also:

- [Caching tutorial for webauthors and webmasters](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)
- [Making sure a webpage is not cached, across all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, I'd recommend to put this piece of code in a `Filter` class which you map on `*.jsp` instead of copypasting the same code over all JSP files for which you'd like to disable the browser cache.